# How to show static file requests on a Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to test proloading of hover images in various browsers, so it'd be nice if the Rails server 
can report what static files (`public/images/foo.png`) are given to the browser.  Is there a way to show or see it (on development server)?

(it is using Rails 2.2.2)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to look in the web server's logs, depending on which web server you are using (`WEBrick`, `nginx`, `mongrel`) the file location can be different.

EDIT: The location of the Mongrel logfile is `RAILS_ROOT/log/mongrel.log`.

Comment: it is using Mongrel... do you know where it is?

Comment: I don't see it in there... although there might be some config details I am not aware of...